# How to get the Percentage of memory utilization using WMIC in batch script?

Tags: windows, batch-file, scripting

I am not getting the result for Percentage of memory utilization in batch script using only W MIC. I am getting only total memory and free memory in bytes.

So how to a get those in Megabytes and how to calculate percentage of memory utilization?

Code :-

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set Times=0
for /f "skip=1" %%p in ('wmic cpu get loadpercentage') do (
    set Cpusage!Times!=%%p
    set /A Times+=1
)

echo CPU Percentage = %Cpusage0%%%

set Times=0
for /f "skip=1" %%p in ('wmic ComputerSystem get TotalPhysicalMemory') do (
    set totalMem!Times!=%%p
    set /A Times+=1
)

set Times=0
for /f "skip=1" %%p in ('wmic OS get FreePhysicalMemory') do (
    set availableMem!Times!=%%p
    set /A Times+=1
)

set Times=0
for /f "skip=1" %%p in ('wmic OS get FreePhysicalMemory ^|findstr physical') do (
    set /a UsedMem= totalMem - availableMem
    set usedMem!Times!=%%p
    set /A Times+=1
)
set /a usedpercent=(usedMem*100)/totalMem

echo Free MEMORY = %availableMem0% Bytes
echo Total MEMORY = %totalMem0% Bytes
echo Used MEMORY = %UsedMem0% Bytes
echo Memory Utilization = %usedpercent0%%%

pause
```

Comment: I'm afraid that this task is unsolvable in `cmd`. Next command `for /f "skip=1" %G in ('wmic ComputerSystem get TotalPhysicalMemory') do @for %g in (%G) do set /a %g` returns `Invalid number.  Numbers are limited to 32-bits of precision`. Switch to PowerShell.

Comment: I have added one more code(code Number 2) regarding the same, please have a look and help to accomplish.i need the output like for ex :-                       Total Memory: 8105 MB
Used Memory: 3760 MB
Free Memory: 4345 MB
MEMORY usage = 46%
CPU Usage = 2% , i have already achieve this output by using system info but i need the same should be in WMIC. please help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` should be used usually only once in a batch file if there is no real necessity to use `setlocal` multiple times. This command does not just enable delayed expansion mode. It **always** copies also the entire current environment table (which can be up to 64 MB), the current states of command extension and delayed expansion, and the current directory path on stack (memory). The number of such environment pushes on stack is not unlimited. At least use `endlocal` between to avoid an early exit of batch processing because of a stack overflow. For more details see the answers on:

- [Echoing a URL in Batch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31360955/3074564)
- [Why is my cd %myVar% being ignored?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33484400/3074564)

Even 64-bit Windows command processor (`cmd.exe`) uses 32-bit signed integers. Therefore the value range is limited to -2.147.483.648 to +2.147.483.647. In other words arithmetic operations with 2 GB and more can't be done without integer overflows producing wrong results.

Here is a commented batch file which does not work for all possible installed RAM configurations, but works for those which are typical in year 2016: 2 GB, 4 GB, 8 GB, 16 GB and 32 GB.

```
@echo off

rem Note: KB = KiB, MB = MiB and GB = GiB in this batch file, see
rem       https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte for details on GiB.

rem Create a copy of current environment variables. Enabling additionally
rem delayed environment variable expansion is not required for this task.
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem The command WMIC with the parameters CPU GET LoadPercentage outputs
rem one line per processor. The output of WMIC is in UTF-16 LE with BOM.
rem The output is redirected to a temporary file which is printed by
rem command TYPE to STDOUT which makes a better job on UNICODE to ASCII
rem conversion as command FOR. Note: 1 processor can have 1 or more cores.

set "CpuUsage=0"
set "Processors=0"
%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\wmic.exe CPU GET LoadPercentage >"%TEMP%\cpu_usage.tmp"
for /F "skip=1" %%P in ('type "%TEMP%\cpu_usage.tmp"') do (
    set /A CpuUsage+=%%P
    set /A Processors+=1
)
del "%TEMP%\cpu_usage.tmp"

rem Calculate the CPU usage as percentage value of all processors.
set /A CpuUsage/=Processors
goto GetTotalMemory

rem Output of WMIC is in UTF-16 LE with BOM. The interpretation of this
rem output in ASCII/OEM can result in processing three lines instead of
rem just two with third line being just a carriage return. Therefore exit
rem each loop after assigning the value of second line to the variable.

:GetTotalMemory
for /F "skip=1" %%M in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\wmic.exe ComputerSystem GET TotalPhysicalMemory') do set "TotalMemory=%%M" & goto GetAvailableMemory
:GetAvailableMemory
for /F "skip=1" %%M in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\wmic.exe OS GET FreePhysicalMemory') do set "AvailableMemory=%%M" & goto ProcessValues

rem Total physical memory is in bytes which can be greater 2^31 (= 2 GB)
rem Windows command processor performs arithmetic operations always with
rem 32-bit signed integer. Therefore 2 GB or more installed physical
rem memory exceeds the bit width of a 32-bit signed integer and arithmetic
rem calculations are wrong on 2 GB or more installed memory. To avoid
rem the integer overflow, the last 6 characters are removed from bytes
rem value and the remaining characters are divided by 1073 to get the
rem number of GB. This workaround works only for physical RAM being
rem an exact multiple of 1 GB, i.e. for 1 GB, 2 GB, 4 GB, 8 GB, ...

rem  1 GB =  1.073.741.824 bytes = 2^30
rem  2 GB =  2.147.483.648 bytes = 2^31
rem  4 GB =  4.294.967.296 bytes = 2^32
rem  8 GB =  8.589.934.592 bytes = 2^33
rem 16 GB = 17.179.869.184 bytes = 2^34
rem 32 GB = 34.359.738.368 bytes = 2^35

rem But there is one more problem at least on Windows XP x86. About 50 MB
rem of RAM is subtracted as used by Windows itself. This can be seen in
rem system settings when 1.95 GB is displayed although 2 GB is installed.
rem Therefore add 50 MB before dividing by 1073.

:ProcessValues
set "TotalMemory=%TotalMemory:~0,-6%"
set /A TotalMemory+=50
set /A TotalMemory/=1073

rem The total memory in GB must be multiplied by 1024 to get the
rem total physical memory in MB which is always small enough to
rem be calculated with a 32-bit signed integer.

set /A TotalMemory*=1024

rem The available memory is in KB and therefore there is
rem no problem with value range of 32-bit signed integer.

set /A AvailableMemory/=1024

rem So the used memory in MB can be determined easily.

set /A UsedMemory=TotalMemory - AvailableMemory

rem It is necessary to calculate the percentage value in MB instead of
rem KB to avoid a 32-bit signed integer overflow on 32 GB RAM and nearly
rem entire RAM is available because used is just a small amount of RAM.

set /A UsedPercent=(UsedMemory * 100) / TotalMemory

if "%Processors%" == "1" (
    set "ProcessorInfo="
) else (
    set "ProcessorInfo= of %Processors% processors"
)
echo CPU percentage: %CpuUsage% %%%ProcessorInfo%
echo Free memory:    %AvailableMemory% MB
echo Total memory:   %TotalMemory% MB
echo Used memory:    %UsedMemory% MB
echo Memory usage:   %UsedPercent% %%

rem Discard the current environment variable table and restore previous
rem environment variables. The states of command processor extension
rem (default: ON) and delayed expansion (default: OFF) as well as the
rem original current directory are restored by this command although
rem not modified at all by the commands above.
endlocal
```

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `del /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `rem /?`
- `setlocal /?`
- `set /?`
- `type /?`
- `wmic /?`
- `wmic CPU get /?`
- `wmic OS get /?`
- `wmic ComputerSystem get /?`

Answer (score 2):

`TotalPhysicalMemory` property of [`Win32_ComputerSystem` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394102(v=vs.85).aspx) (in bytes, **uint64** data type) overreachs `set /A` batch file integer arithmetic limitation (see [`set` command](http://ss64.com/nt/set.html)): it's limited to 32-bits of precision (corresponds to **uint32** data type) i.e. cca ±2 [gibibytes (`GiB`)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibibyte).

Let's capture output from [`Systeminfo` command](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491007.aspx) which is in [mebibytes (`MiB`)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mebibyte):

```
==> systeminfo | find /I "Physical Memory"

Total Physical Memory:     8 137 MB
Available Physical Memory: 4 210 MB

==>
```

therefore `set /A` should suffice: 32-bit limitation is overwhelmed.

Explanation in `rem` comments:

```
@ECHO OFF >NUL
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions
echo(---
set "_memo_total="
    rem unfortunately, next command is (supposedly) locale dependent
for /F "tokens=1,* delims=:" %%G in ('
        systeminfo^|find /I "Physical Memory"
                                    ') do (
  set "_memo_inuse="
      rem remove spaces including no-break spaces
  for %%g in (%%H) do if /I NOT "%%g"=="MB" set "_memo_inuse=!_memo_inuse!%%g"
  if defined _memo_total ( set "_memo_avail=!_memo_inuse!" 
                  ) else ( set "_memo_total=!_memo_inuse!" )
  echo !_memo_inuse! [MB] %%G 
)
set /A "_memo_inuse=_memo_total - _memo_avail"
    rem in integer arithmetics: calculate percentage multipled by 100 
set /A "_perc_inuse=10000 * _memo_inuse / _memo_total"
set /A "_perc_avail=10000 * _memo_avail / _memo_total"
    rem debugging: mostly 9999 as `set /A` trucates quotients instead of rounding  
set /A "_perc__suma=_perc_inuse + _perc_avail
echo(---
call :formatpercent _perc_avail
call :formatpercent _perc_inuse
call :formatpercent _perc__suma
    rem display results
set _
ENDLOCAL
goto :eof

:formatpercent
    rem         simulates division by 100

    rem input : variable NAME (i.e. passed by reference)
    rem         it's value could vary from   0 to 10000   format mask ####0  
    rem output: variable VALUE 
    rem             respectively vary from .00 to 100.00  format mask ###.00
if NOT defined %1 goto :eof
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
  set "aux5=     !%1!"
  set "aux5=%aux5:~-5%"
      rem repair unacceptable format mask ###.#0 to ###.00
  set "auxx=%aux5:~3,1%
  if "%auxx%"==" " set "aux5=%aux5:~0,3%0%aux5:~4%"
      REM       rem change format mask from ###.00 to common ##0.00
      REM   set "auxx=%aux5:~2,1%
      REM   if "%auxx%"==" " set "aux5=%aux5:~0,2%0%aux5:~3%" 
  set "aux6=%aux5:~0,3%.%aux5:~3%"
ENDLOCAL&set "%1=%aux6%"
goto :eof
```

**Output**:

```
==> D:\bat\SO\37338476a.bat
---
8137 [MB] Total Physical Memory
4166 [MB] Available Physical Memory
---
_memo_avail=4166
_memo_inuse=3971
_memo_total=8137
_perc_avail= 51.19
_perc_inuse= 48.80
_perc__suma= 99.99

==>
```

**Accuracy, tolerance** (measured with `8 GiB` installed memory):  ==> **good**

- `Capacity=8589934592`                from `Win32_PhysicalMemory` class == `8 GiB`
- `TotalPhysicalMemory=8531865600`     from `Win32_ComputerSystem` class == `8136.62 MiB`
- `Total Physical Memory:    8 137 MB` from `systeminfo` command == `8137 MiB`

**Response time** (`systeminfo` is considerably slower than `wmic`): ==> **poor**

Comment: BY Using systeminfo is very easy to get the output in MB, but it will check all the hotfix and NIC information of the system, i hope systeminfo is not a good idea when we implement this script in server , it will take more cpu usage , so only i prefer WMIC

Comment: So please help me in WMIC script to get this same output

Comment: @T.Anand see [my comment to your question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37338476/how-to-get-the-of-memory-utilization-using-wmic-in-batch-script/37357698?noredirect=1#comment62199573_37338476) You probably need to adjust [npocmaka's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37348677/3439404) to match your circumstances and requirements. Sorry, I can't write scripts for anyone at StackExchange.com.  I only can take up a challenge in solving interesting problems…

Answer (score 1):

you can alter the output to fit your needs:

```
@if (@X)==(@Y) @end /* JScript comment
    @echo off
    cscript //E:JScript //nologo "%~f0"
    exit /b %errorlevel%

@if (@X)==(@Y) @end JScript comment */

var aBytes=GetObject('winmgmts:').ExecQuery('Select * from Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfOS_Memory').ItemIndex(0).AvailableBytes;
var tBytes=GetObject('winmgmts:').ExecQuery('Select * from Win32_ComputerSystem').ItemIndex(0).TotalPhysicalMemory;
WScript.Echo("available:"+aBytes+"\ntotal:"+tBytes);
var totalMemoryUsed=(tBytes-aBytes)*100/tBytes;
WScript.Echo("used in % -"+totalMemoryUsed);
```